# Java doing different things based on generic type

Tags: java, generics

As of now I have an object that looks similar to the below.

```
public class DataField implements JSONable
{
    public final String name;
    public final Class<?> typeClass;
    private Object data;

    public <T> DataField(String name, Class<T> typeClass)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.typeClass = typeClass;

        data = null;
    }
    public <T> T getData(Class<T> passClass)
    {
        if(!typeClass.equals(passClass))
            throw new TypeMismatchException("Type mismatch");
        return passClass.cast(data);
    }
    public <T> T setData(T obj, Class<T> passClass)
    {
        if(!typeClass.equals(passClass))
            throw new TypeMismatchException("Type mismatch");
        data = (Object) obj;
    }
    public String toJSON()
    {
        //The part that bugs me
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        switch(type)
        {
        case "myPackage.DataField":
            if(isArray)
                return TakesADataObjOrCollectionOfDataObjs(sb,Arrays.asList(get(DataObj[].class)));
            else
                return TakesADataObjOrCollectionOfDataObjs(sb,get(DataObj.class));
        break;
        default:
            if(isArray)
                TakesAnObjectOrCollection(sb,Arrays.asList(get(Object[].class)));
            else
               TakesAnObjectOrCollection(sb,get(Object.class));
        break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
//I did not include code for DataObj but it has a HashMap<String,DataField>
//fields on it and two functions for getting and setting field data 
//without actually divulging the field objects themselves.
```

**Background:** The problem is with this last `toJSON` function. I have two different functions (listed here as `TakesADataObjOrCollectionOfDataObjs` and `TakesAnObjectOrCollection`) which do different things based on if the object implements `JSONable` or not. Now I cannot simplify these all down to one function and let the compiler choose because with type erasure, I cannot have a function that takes both `Collection<?>` and `Collection<? extends JSONable>` as they have the same function signature. 
It was easy when I only had to differentiate between just `Object` and `DataObj` types (it's a pretty simple check and all I have to do is pass in the `Class<?>` of the type we're working with) but now I need to start storing `List<?>` and `List<? extends JSONable>`.
**Current Solution:** I do have a bit of code for this solution but it is not the same as what's pictured above. The current solution is to just include the type of the generic that I'm using as well like having `typeClass` and a `genericTypeClass`. The problem with this is it starts becoming really messy because:

- All appropriate methods that take just `typeClass` would need two methods now, one that takes both `typeClass` and `genericTypeClass` and one that takes `typeClass` but sets `genericTypeClass` to null.
- I'd having much more trouble performing type checks (for get and set) if I could even do it at all for some instances.
- The `toJSON` switch statement would be filled with more cases, one for each supported generic, and then under each of those, checking the `genericTypeClass` to see if it's a `DataObj` or not.

**Question:** Is there any other way that I could create this class to do what I want (store differing data yet still be able to output different JSON based on the type the `DataField` holds)?
Hopefully just explaining the situation and not asking 3 or 4 other related questions will stop me from falling prey to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) by just asking this.

Comment: `getData()` and `setData()` look wrong to me, it's like you're basically replicating what a regular field of a regular POJO is doing anyway.

Comment: All the `DataFields` residing on the `DataObjs` are populated from a few different sources (databases, excel spreadsheets, etc). The reason I have these objects is so I can iterate over multiple objects including their fields to retrieve and store certain information without using reflection. Even with reflection it would make certain things very hard or impossible to do or require much more hand typed code for each different object and field of a POJO.

Comment: If you have to do this, then you have to accept that your code will be somewhat messy. What most data serialisation frameworks I've seen  (XStream for example) do is they create a `Converter` interface, each implementation of which will do the conversion to/from a certain Java class. Then you create a `Map<Class<?>, Converter<Class<?>>` map that you can use to look up dynamically which converter to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use **Jackson** to convert your objects into **JSON Strings**.

It is really easy to get to work (seriously) and it could save you a lot of time and potential errors... It also supports some features that you could use, I'm thinking about the serialization of `List`s for example :)

Here is a link to an [interesting blog to get you going with Jackson Json](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/).
And here is a link to [the download page for Jackson Json](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload).

---

Below is a little example I just made to show you how to work with it:

```
public class Main {
    public final String mainStr = "Hello";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("Serialized Main: " + om.writeValueAsString(new Main()));
        System.out.println("Serialized A: " + om.writeValueAsString(new A()));
        System.out.println("Serialized AA: " + om.writeValueAsString(new AA()));
        System.out.println("Serialized B: " + om.writeValueAsString(new B()));
        System.out.println("Serialized List of A: " + om.writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonList(new A())));
    }
    
    static class A extends Main {
        public final String aStr = "World";
        public final int aInt = 42;
    }
    
    static class AA extends A {
        public final String aaStr = "Foo";
    }

    static class B {
        public final String bStr = "Bar";
        public final boolean bBool = true;
    }
}
```

Ouptut:

```
Serialized Main: {"mainStr":"Hello"}
Serialized A: {"mainStr":"Hello","aStr":"World","aInt":42}
Serialized AA: {"mainStr":"Hello","aStr":"World","aInt":42,"aaStr":"Foo"}
Serialized B: {"bStr":"Bar","bBool":true}
Serialized List of A: [{"mainStr":"Hello","aStr":"World","aInt":42}]
```

If you have troubles making it work, we could discuss it on [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and I could give you more help there.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm currently looking into it but I don't think the time constraints will allow me to start over with something new. I'm already pretty far into what I have right now. I will +1 this answer if I see it would fit my situation regardless of if I'll use it or not though.

Comment: Fair enough. Don't give up, though, I really believe that this solution is the right one! And don't hesitate to ask for more help, you might just miss something huge that could really make your life much easier otherwise ;) Good luck.